# How to perform a conditional update using Fatfree framework's ORM

Tags: php, state-machine, fat-free-framework

The situation consists of attempting to use F3 ORM (MySQL) with a state machine. A transaction/action should only be performed/persisted to the database if the original status allows for the transition to occur.

The code below loads the object, applies the new state, creates a new transaction, and attempts to ensure that the state in the database is as expected by updating the record to the new state.

```php
$instance = $f3->get('domainObject')->load(['id=?', $id]);

$stateMachine = new StateMachine($instance, $config);
$originalState = $instance->stateA;
  
$stateMachine->apply($body['state']);

$db->begin();
$db->exec(
  'UPDATE domainObject SET stateA=? WHERE stateA=?',
  $instance->stateA,
  $originalState
);
$instance->save();
$db->commit();
```

Even though the update and the save is within the same transaction the modification occurs even if the update fails to update the record (say when the `stateA` has changed).

How can I use F3 ORM to conditionally update the model with a clause that states `stateA` should be a certain value?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the FF ORM - is `StateMachine` part of that library?

Comment: How does the state machine reject an update that cannot happen - does it raise an exception? If so I assume that the `save()` should be wrapped in a try-catch, so that the transaction can be rolled back.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the state machine. The applied state modifies the model loaded from F3, which then needs updating in the db.

Comment: I added the state machine code into the question as it adds context / restraints to the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `$instance` is an instance of `DB\SQL\Mapper` and that `stateMachine->apply($body['state'])` modifies `$instance->stateA`, then it should be as simple as:

```php
$instance = $f3->get('domainObject')->load(['id=?', $id]);

$stateMachine = new StateMachine($instance, $config);

$instance->save();
```

The `save()` method triggers an `UPDATE` query, only if a field has been changed.

NB: be careful that the `load()` method may return `FALSE`. Your code should handle that case.

Comment: Saving directly over the record without checking the value of stateA might modify a record that has already been changed. Let's say the states for stateA are a->b->c. We might update the state to b whereas someone else has already updated the state to c. Within a state machine this shouldn't happen.